# Unable to find an element on DOM having two classes using expect test library with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

Is there any way to find an element by second class name or by element having two or more class names while testing React-Redux components?

E.g., I have a div:

```html
<div className="navigations active">
....
</div>
```

Though I am able to find it by first class-name

```js
const wrapper = mount(
   <Provider store={store}>
       <TodoApp />
   </Provider>
);

expect(wrapper.find('.navigations ')).toHaveLength(4);
```

but unable to find it by second class name. E.g.:

`expect(wrapper.find('.active')).toHaveLength(1);`

It always give me length of zero, but the active class is attached to DOM.
I just want to know if there is any way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do both... I've created quick test to check your example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

const MyComp = ({active}) => <div className={`navigations${active ? ' active': ''}`} />;

describe('Name of the group', () => {
  it('should ', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <>
        <MyComp />
        <MyComp active/>
        <MyComp />
        <MyComp />
      </>,
    );

    expect(wrapper.find('.navigations')).toHaveLength(4);
    expect(wrapper.find('.active')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: do it with redux

Comment: Share your code with some sandbox like codebin etc. It would be easier

Comment: Tell me your github username, so I can give access to you

Comment: My github is `MaciejTrojniarz`